# Find all duplicates in a list and populate them in same order in a new list

Tags: python

I have found the following code on Stack Overflow for creating new list of unique values recursively, but it doesn't work for  me no matter how I tweak it for my requirement in the title. What is wrong here?

My requirement is for input `[1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]` the output should be `[2,3,4]` or for the input `[1,2,24,2,1]` the output should be `[1,2]`.

The code I am trying is as below:

```
def find_duplicates(list_of_numbers):
    #start writing your code here
    dup_list=[]
    if len(list_of_numbers) < 1:
        dup_list=[]
    else:
        if list_of_numbers[0] in list_of_numbers[1:]:
            print(list_of_numbers[0])
            dup_list=[list_of_numbers[0]]+find_duplicates(list_of_numbers[1:])
        else:
            dup_list=find_duplicates(list_of_numbers[1:])
            
    return dup_list


list_of_numbers=[1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]
list_of_duplicates=find_duplicates(list_of_numbers)
print(list_of_duplicates)
```

Comment: In case you have found it in a question, try to look at the answers below.

Comment: I don't think you can do it recursively like this, because the recursive call doesn't know what values were duplicates in the caller.

Comment: it seems you are picking values whose elements duplicated. ie `from collections import Counter;  [i for i,j in Counter([1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]).items() if j>1]`

Answer (score 0):

You will find the Counter class from the collections module very helpful.

For example:

```
from collections import Counter

def find_duplicates(list_of_numbers):
    return [n for n, c in Counter(list_of_numbers).items() if c > 1]

data = [
    [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],
    [1,2,24,2,1]
]

for d in data:
    print(find_duplicates(d))
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 3, 4]
[1, 2]
```